# How to install swi-prolog as a shared library?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to develop an expert system using prolog as an inference engine and python as interface. I already have the SWI-prolog installed in my machine, but, i can't import the interface PySwip because SWI-Prolog is not installed as a shared library. I've followed some tutorials in order to get SWI-prolog correctly installed but, it failed.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install swi-prolog swi-prolog-nox
```

Provides

```
.
/usr/lib/libswipl.a
/usr/lib/libswipl.so
/usr/lib/libswipl.so.7.2
/usr/lib/libswipl.so.7.2.3
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/swipl.pc
.
```

You can read the complete file list here http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/swi-prolog-nox/filelist

Comment: it still keeps saying that the SWI-Prolog is not installed as a shared library...

Comment: if ir helps, in the webpage of pyswip is listed the riquirements for running the interface. it's the following: 
Python 2.3 and higher.
ctypes 1.0 and higher.
SWI-Prolog 5.6.x and higher (not the development branch).
libpl as a shared library.

Comment: after the installation as you said before, there're no files such as the ones you listed above

Comment: @Roney I think the issue is actually that the library basename has been changed (from `libpl` to `libswipl`) - see [libpl.so in Prolog version 6.6.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22789051/4440445) for example. As a 'hail mary' you could try symlinking the new libs to the old name e.g. `sudo ln -s libswipl.so /usr/lib/libpl.so`